# Организация запроса к MS SQL Server (EF 6) используя LINQ

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

при проектировании собственного проекта на языке С # технологии WPF и запроса к данным на Entity Framework 6 встал вопрос как реализовать один запрос.
У меня есть 4 класса сущностей, которые соответственно генерируются в таблицы:

```
class Spetsialnist
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string NameSpets {get; set;}
}

class Group
{
   public int id {get; set;}
   public string NumberGroup {get; set;}
   public int SpetsId;
}

class Student
{
   public int id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int GroupId {get; set;}     
}

class Otsinka
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public double mark {get;set;}
    public int semestr {get;set;}
    public int StudentId {get;set;)
}
```

Контекст данных:

```
class StudentContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Vnz> Vnzs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Vidilena> Vidilenas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Spetsialnist> Spetsialnists { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Otsinka> Otsinkas { get; set; }
}
```

Помогите реализовать запрос и получить список из двух значений (StudentName, AverageMark) на основе NameSpets (тоесть пользователь выбирает определенную специальность к которой привязана группа в свою очередь к группе привязан студент а также к студенту привязаны его оценки), как при данной конструкции сделать выборку правильно с учётом выбора семестра, а также должно подсчитать у каждого студента средний балл.

Comment: ну вы чтото сами пробовали?

Comment: где у вас навигационные свойства? Как оценки связаны вообще с чем либо?

Comment: Как выглядит контекст данных?

Comment: в общем, много вопросов, мало ответов. Дополняйте вопрос данными, пока ничего особо сказать нечего.

Comment: Оценки связаны по id студента, просто на данной схеме не получилось добавить

Comment: что не получилось? `public int StudentId {get;set;}` добавить в текст или что?

Comment: class StudentContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Vnz> Vnzs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Vidilena> Vidilenas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Spetsialnist> Spetsialnists { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Otsinka> Otsinkas { get; set; }
    }

Comment: это контекст данных

Comment: я делал без навигационных свойств

Comment: Всю новую информацию добавляйте в вопрос (вы можете его редактировать), и вы ответили не на все вопросы.

Comment: `я делал без навигационных свойств` и вот это очень зря. Как вы планируете обеспечить целостность данных без внешних ключей?

Comment: я знаю что в ef core есть возможность установки каскадного удаления данных, есть ли данная фича в ef 6? Я только из-за этого не сделал нав. свойства

Comment: Этого я сказал не могу, должно быть, наверное. Но навигационные свойство это не только каскадное удаление, это внешние ключи, как вы без них работать собрались?

Comment: Настройка каскадного удаления - фича SQL, которую поддерживал и EF5 и EF6, а потом это уже в Core перенесли. Зря обходили, реляционная база без навигационных свойств/внешних ключей - это просто ничто.

Comment: Можно мне немного поныть? Как можно было не сделать запрос в гугл "EF 6 cascade delete" и [сразу узнать](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/cascade-delete-in-code-first.aspx), есть или нет удаление? "Я не знаю" легко превращается в "я теперь знаю".